# How to convert JSON to Array by PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have following JSON data received.

```
{
    "app": "000",
    "members":[
        {
            "name":{
                "value": "PIYO"
            },
            "email":{
                "value": "piyo@alk.jp"
            }
        },
        {
            "name":{
                "value": "HOGE"
            },
            "email":{
                "value": "hoge@alk.jp"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to convert it to following array.

```
[["name" => "PIYO", "email" => "piyo@alk.jp"], ["name" => "HOGE", "email" => "hoge@alk.jp"]]
```

How can I handle it?
Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Don't forget that $json must be in string.

I tried to test result on PHP.

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "app": "000",
    "members":[
        {
            "name":{
                "value": "PIYO"
            },
            "email":{
                "value": "piyo@alk.jp"
            }
        },
        {
            "name":{
                "value": "HOGE"
            },
            "email":{
                "value": "hoge@alk.jp"
            }
        }
    ]
}';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($array['members']);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [value] => PIYO
                )

            [email] => Array
                (
                    [value] => piyo@alk.jp
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [value] => HOGE
                )

            [email] => Array
                (
                    [value] => hoge@alk.jp
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$phparray = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained how and why this affects the problem at hand. Simply dumping code is less likely to help the OP and any inexperienced future readers as well. @Danial No, it wouldn't. The second parameter (`true`) specifies that the JSON should be converted as an associative array.

Answer (score -2):

```
$foo = json_decode($json,true);
$members = $foo['members'];
```

$members will be the array you want.

Comment: I have error 'ErrorException: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in file' . Please give me an advice.

Comment: Im "assuming" you're assigning your json string to $json.

Comment: This would still produce an array of stdClass objects, which is not the goal OP specifies.

Comment: Late night helping is discouraged. I prefer objects; an array of objects is what I'd want in this case.